# Code Igniter download file

Tags: php, codeigniter

I upload some documents using codeigniter to 'public/upload' folder. It is successful. Then I want those files to be displayed and download. The display is ok, but can you please provide me some code sample to download. I tried with several methods, but not working

Here is my controller - home.php

```
function downloadtest() {
    $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
    if (isset($_SESSION) && isset($session_data['rolename'])) {
      $data['username'] = $session_data['username'];       
      $this->load->view('vwHomeHeader', $data);
      $this->load->view('vwHomeMenu', $data);
      $this->load->view('vwdown',$data);
      $this->load->view('vwHomeFooter', $data);
    } else {
      $this->load->view('vwLogin');
    }
```

Here is the view - vwdown.php

```
<?php      
    $this->load->helper('directory'); 
    $dir = "public/upload"; 
    $map = directory_map($dir);

foreach ($map as $k){
 echo '<a>'.basename($dir)."/".$k.'</a>'.'<br>';   
}       
?>
```

Comment: your `a` tag has no `href`

Comment: what should I put for the href?

Comment: In here <a href=""></a>

Comment: Yes.. I mean what path should be redirected for it to download into ??

Answer (score 1):

you can also use download helper of codeigniter
just follow this link

> [codeigniter official guide](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/download_helper.html)